# Is there a way to mark a Woocommerce order as Complete by customer?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am dropshipping from Aliexpress and want to give an option to customers on orders page to mark order as complete. The order tracking with any dropshipping is pretty dubious and you may not see an order as delivered even after quite a long time after actual delivery.

Having an option of marking order as complete by customers themselves will reduce some of my worry about incomplete orders.

Could not find any plugins about this feature.

Comment: I don't know if it's there but as i think you can do one thing here. Create a custom account/orders page where you can list their orders along with status and and also a button like "received" or something. On click on the button you can add ajax action where it updates the particular product status

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button under the "Actions" column, with "Mark as completed". 
You can use this guide to achieve this: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/adding-columns-woocommerce-orders-list/

Also, you will need to hook it to ajax call (or post) and mark the order as completed.

There is a security risk here, if some hacker will try to use your ajax and pass order IDs you will see all your orders as completed. So pass the **order key** along with this call and make sure you validate it prior to moving it to completed (use $order->key_is_valid)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @shir.
Could you give me any reference for adding ajax calls?

Comment: Sure. This is a very extensive guide: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example/ . This is a short guide: https://sharewebdesign.com/blog/wordpress-ajax-call/